# Outline grouped plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to outline the shape of the graph produced by a group plot.

Using this code:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(babynames)
library(dplyr)

# Keep only 3 names
don <- babynames %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Ashley", "Patricia", "Helen")) %>%
  filter(sex=="F")
  
# Plot
don %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=year, y=n, group=name, color=name)) +
    geom_line()
```

I get this:
[image: grouped plot]

Is it possible to keep only the outline of the produced graph?
Example output:

[image: Final output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a `ggplot2` way to do this but here one attempt using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

don %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=year, y=n, group=name, color=name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

The logic here is we keep only the row with max `n` value for each `year` so it removes all those lines which are being plotted below the outline line that we want.